# Ubuntu remap a broken key

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit

I have an Asus U35JC running a 64bit Ubuntu and I recently found out that one of my keys, <kbd>[</kbd> is not functioning at all.

Can somebody suggest a neat way of replacing that key with another one, e.g. the Windows key or the CAPS lock key?

I tried reading info on many sites but I'm afraid I might need a detailed explanation of how to deal with `xev`.

Comment: Does it need to work in X or also on the console? In the case of X look at `xmodmap`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [xmodmap](https://superuser.com/questions/485225/ubuntu-remap-a-broken-key):

```
xmodmap -e "remove lock = Caps_Lock" && xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = bracketleft"
```